# Read contents of KML file into CSV format using Python (BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, kml, csv, kmz, extract

I have a KML file called `Layers.KML` which has multiple sub folders - `Tree_Heights_Elevations`, `20190516 - Chain Link Fence`, `20190516 - Clearing Limits`, `2016-0516 - Solar Array` .

`Tree_Heights_Elevations` subfolders contain multiple points, each of which contains tree heights. Here is the screen shot of the KML file

[image]

As you can see in the image above -

`Layers.KML` has another folder which is `Tree_Heights_Elevations` which has multiple points. Eg: `ASSPOTX` which has some information. I want to extract value of `Elevation`.

I am using BeautifulSoup Python package but unable to extract the Elevation. Could anyone guide me the right way to extract data. I do not know if this is the simplest way to extract data into CSV

```
import csv, os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

inputfile = "Layers.KML"
with open(inputfile, 'r') as f:
  soup = BeautifulSoup(f)


  for node in soup.select('Tree_Heights_Elevations'):
       print(node)
```

Comment: I think the simplest way of extracting this information would be using OGR

Comment: @MarceloVilla these tables are stored as HTML in a `<![CDATA[` block in the `<description>` tag of the KML.  OGR doesn't parse the HTML, it just dumps it into the feature description property.

Comment: @AakashRaj please edit your question to include some sample data.

Comment: @user2856 I dont know how can I add the data. But if you look at the screenshot of GoogleEarth there is a KML file `Layers.KML` which has subfolder `Tree_Height_Elevations` which has over 400 files. One such files selected `ASSPOTX` which has Elevation info (highlighed in yellow). I was to parse it and extract data into a csv form.

Comment: As mentioned by @user2856, the data you're trying to extract is in an HTML table in each KML feature's description tag.  This is an unfortunate result of using ESRI's ArcGIS and its KML export tools, which cram all the attribute data into an HTML blob. A better practice, which many other KML exporters do, is to write the attributes into ExtendedData tags in the KML feature itself, and then use a balloon template to construct the balloon content. To extract the data, you'll want to parse the description tags out of each KML feature, and then the HTML from each of those.